# Delete an value from a list if this value exists in a list of dictionarys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict, e.g:

```
a = {1: {1:2, 3:4}, 2: {4:5, 6:7}}
```

and a list with dictionarys, eg:

```
b = [{1:2, 3:4}, {9:10}]
```

How can I delete an specific item from my "a" dict if any values of "a" is in list b?

I need to get this output:

```
a = {2: {4:5, 6:7}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> a = {1: {1:2, 3:4}, 2: {4:5, 6:7}}
>>> b = [{1:2, 3:4}, {9:10}]
>>> {k:v for k,v in a.items() if v not in b}
{2: {4: 5, 6: 7}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {key: value for key, value in a.items() if value not in b}
```

This is fairly straightforward with a list comprehension. If you're expecting a lot of items in `b`, it may be faster to use set operations:

```
b_set = {frozenset(d.items()) for d in b}
a = {key: value for key, value in a.items()
     if frozenset(value.items()) not in b_set}
```